# Seperate SCSS for different Angular modules

Tags: angular, sass, angular-ui-router

Is there any way to separate scss for separate modules. In details if I have 2 modules called `module_1` and `module_2` and 2 scss files called `module_1.scss` and `module_2.scss`. I want my angular module_1 to load other scss except `module_2.scss` and similarly for module_2 I don't want `module_1.scss` to get loaded. How can I achieve this in angular.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since angular has styles imported at the component level, you can create `module_1.scss` and `module_2.scss` -- and then for each container-level component in the modules, add the appropriate scss file to the styles array

Example module_1 > component_foo

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-foo',
  templateUrl: './foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../module_1.scss']
})
```

Example module_2 > component_bar

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar',
  templateUrl: './bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../module_2.scss']
})
```

Because of this, I would recommend trying to group components into parent "containers" of other small/dumb child components so only the parent needs the styles imported